# Using :after CSS to generate full-screen mask

Tags: html, css

Here is my attempts about it: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/GA7GC/)

Because I'm overriding some existing styles, I need to add a translucent mask behind my `box`

```
.box {
position:fixed;
background:red;
height:50%;
width:200px;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
z-index:1000;
margin:auto;
}

.box:after {
content:"";
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
z-index:999;
}
```

See the sample in the fiddle, I don't understand why the box is also covered by its `:after` style?

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `:after` pseudo element defines a pseudo content that is *after* the *real* content of the `.box`. It is the *pseudo child* of the `.box`. So if your pseudo element would be really defined in DOM it would look like

```
<div class="box">
    <p>some real content</p>
    <div class="box-after"></div>
</div>
```

**NOT like this:**

```
<div class="box">
    <p>some real content</p>
</div>
<div class="box-after"></div>
```

**EDIT**:
To resolve the problem you can simply wrap all the inner content of `.box` with another div.

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="inner-box">inner content</div>
</div>
```

Then with some minor changes to CSS you would come up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/GA7GC/2/.

Comment: Thanks! Is that mean I can't realize it unless making modification on source html?

Comment: That's true. I'll try to prepare a solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this answer ([Full width background element with pseudo-class - z-index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505862/full-width-background-element-with-pseudo-class-z-index)) I've managed to make fullscreen mask using just css.

```css
.dialog
{
 position: absolute;
 width: 90%;
 height: 80%;
 top:10%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 2000;
 padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}


.dialog::before{
 content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
 background: #464646;
 border-radius: 8px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:-1;
}

.dialog::after{
 content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: translate(-50%,-20%);
  z-index: -100;
  opacity: .7;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div> text </div>
<div class="dialog">
This is dialog
</div>
```